# How can I introduce a new column which does not count in every line?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have following dataframe about auctions:

| id.product_permutation | id.iteration | property.product | property.price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 200 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 300 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 400 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 100 |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | 200 |
| 1 | 6 | 3 | 300 |
| 1 | 7 | 2 | 500 |
| 1 | 8 | 2 | 600 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 300 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 400 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 300 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 | 700 |
| 2 | 6 | 2 | 800 |
| 2 | 7 | 2 | 900 |
| 2 | 8 | 2 | 700 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 200 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

There are 3 different products in the auction and the column **property.product** tells which product is for sale at the moment. If the product number in property.product changes then the product is sold.
**property.price** tells what the price is at the moment.
If the number in **id.product_permutation** changes then the whole auction is over, all 3 items are sold and a new auction starts (with the same 3 items).

Now I would like to introduce a new column **amount_of_sold_items** which counts how many products were already sold (like in the following). I tried a lot, but unfortunately I do not get the desired result. Can anyone help me please to solve this issue?

| id.product_permutation | id.iteration | property.product | property.price | amount_of_sold_items |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 200 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 300 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 400 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 100 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | 200 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 | 3 | 300 | 1 |
| 1 | 7 | 2 | 500 | 2 |
| 1 | 8 | 2 | 600 | 2 |
| 1 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 300 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 400 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 200 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 300 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 | 700 | 2 |
| 2 | 6 | 2 | 800 | 2 |
| 2 | 7 | 2 | 900 | 2 |
| 2 | 8 | 2 | 700 | 2 |
| 2 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 200 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df["n_items_sold"] = (df.groupby("id.product_permutation")["property.product"]
                        .transform(lambda x: x.diff().ne(0, fill_value=0).cumsum()))
```

For each `id.product_permutation` group, we assign a new series that looks at the turning points via difference not being equal to 0 (`fill_value=0` is there to prevent counting the very first one as a turning point). Cumulative sum of these turning points keeps track of the items sold thus far.

This gives:

```
    id.product_permutation  id.iteration  property.product  property.price  n_items_sold
0                        1             1                 1             200             0
1                        1             2                 1             300             0
2                        1             3                 1             400             0
3                        1             4                 3             100             1
4                        1             5                 3             200             1
5                        1             6                 3             300             1
6                        1             7                 2             500             2
7                        1             8                 2             600             2
8                        2             1                 3             300             0
9                        2             2                 3             400             0
10                       2             3                 1             200             1
11                       2             4                 1             300             1
12                       2             5                 2             700             2
13                       2             6                 2             800             2
14                       2             7                 2             900             2
15                       2             8                 2             700             2
16                       3             1                 1             200             0
```

To put `[id_prod_perm, NaN, NaN, NaN, 3]` rows at the end of each `id.product_permuation`, we can detect the changing points of `id.product_permuation` and insert columns to the transposed frame which, in effect, inserts rows to the original one when transposed:

```
# following is [8, 16] for the above example
changing_points = np.where(df["id.product_permutation"]
                             .diff().ne(0, fill_value=0))[0].tolist()

# insert to transpose and then come back
df = df.T
offset = 0  # helper for insertion location
for j, point in enumerate(changing_points, start=1):
    # to the given point, insert a column with the same name
    df.insert(loc=point+offset, column=point, value=[j, *[np.nan]*3, 3],
              allow_duplicates=True)

    # since an insertion enlarges the frame, old changing points
    # need to increase, this is handled by the `offset`
    offset += 1

# go back to original form, and also reset the index to 0..N-1
df = df.T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

to get

```
>>> df

    id.product_permutation  id.iteration  property.product  property.price  n_items_sold
0                      1.0           1.0               1.0           200.0           0.0
1                      1.0           2.0               1.0           300.0           0.0
2                      1.0           3.0               1.0           400.0           0.0
3                      1.0           4.0               3.0           100.0           1.0
4                      1.0           5.0               3.0           200.0           1.0
5                      1.0           6.0               3.0           300.0           1.0
6                      1.0           7.0               2.0           500.0           2.0
7                      1.0           8.0               2.0           600.0           2.0
8                      1.0           NaN               NaN             NaN           3.0
9                      2.0           1.0               3.0           300.0           0.0
10                     2.0           2.0               3.0           400.0           0.0
11                     2.0           3.0               1.0           200.0           1.0
12                     2.0           4.0               1.0           300.0           1.0
13                     2.0           5.0               2.0           700.0           2.0
14                     2.0           6.0               2.0           800.0           2.0
15                     2.0           7.0               2.0           900.0           2.0
16                     2.0           8.0               2.0           700.0           2.0
17                     2.0           NaN               NaN             NaN           3.0
18                     3.0           1.0               1.0           200.0           0.0
```